# python self generating figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I would like to create figures using matplotlib for example, based on matrix data. The matrix has 3 dimensions, x and y are size of a layer and n is the number of layers of my matrix.

I would like to display each layer separatly using an imshow for each layer. The matrix is loaded from a file, and before loading it I don't know the size of the matrix.

How can I automate figure generation ? It is always the same thing, but usually I'm doing it statically:

If I have 3 layer I'm doing it by hand :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
# my plots

fig2 = plt.figure()
# my plots

fig3 = plt.figure()
# my plots
```

But if I don't knowthe number of figure I cannot do it this way. I would like to create it using a loop:

```
for i in range(n):
   figi = plt.figure()
```

But in doing this way I'm overwriting figi every time of course! How can I do to conserve all of my figures ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can store them in a list. Start with `figs = []` and then append: `figs.append(plt.figure())`.  Later you can access them as `figs[0], figs[1], ...`

Comment: yes... of course -.- I lost simplicity this time :D